# Best practices ajax php jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I've a (many) doubts about this topic.

I use a file javascript separated from html/php.. and when I call php codes with ajax, in success I use typical function like this:

```
$('...').on('method', function () {.....});
```

When I want a variable I must pass it in hidden div, ecc. ecc.

I recently realized that I can directly write the code jquery in php-file, so I can also pass variables or use php-code between js.

```
<script>
    $('...').<?php echo ( $a>1 ? "method1" : "method2" ); ?>({.....});
    var x = <?php echo $b; ?>;
    ....
</script>
```

Where is the swindle? or is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: That is correct, you've just realized that a *.php file is actually able to output parsed PHP code.

Comment: As for best practices, it surely isn't inline scripts. If you need values from PHP on pageload, echo them in data attributes where you need them.

Comment: thx adeneo! I'm glad!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is correct. You can actually use *.PHP files for just about anything. You can even us them for CSS! The trick here is that HTML doesn't really care about file extensions, what it DOES care about, is the response header. so I can do something like this to load up a style sheet..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.php">
```

Then, as long as mystyle.php sends this header

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

The browser will take the output as a CSS file. [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) is a more in-depth example.

TL;DR

You can use *.PHP to output just about any type of file. Including Javascript, PHP, HTML, CSS ect ect. Just make sure you are sending the right header at the beginning of the script! :)

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: because recommendation of using PHP this way.. is the wrong use. If you're using PHP for this, you need to learn other languages

Comment: What are yout talking about? PHP is designed as a templating language. I've used PHP to store color codes and generate CSS on the fly.

Comment: [PHP is a popular general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited to web development](https://php.net) - there's no point. With css-preprocessors, it's best to keep server-side to server-side.

Comment: So we shouldn't be using PHP to generate dynamic web pages then either? It's literally the exact same process